# xslt transform multiple data sources

Tags: sql, xml, xslt, aspdotnetstorefront

I am trying to transform 2 data sources coming from sql stored procedures.

Is there any way to use the xsl document() function to combine the two sources into something that one xsl:template can use?  Here's the stored procedure calls:

```
<query name="Products" rowElementName="Product" runif="showproduct">
<sql>
<![CDATA[
exec dbo.BSI_ProductInfo @ProductID, @CustomerLevelID, 1, 0, @affiliateID
]]>
</sql>
<queryparam paramname="@ProductID"       paramtype="request" requestparamname="ProductID"       sqlDataType="int" defvalue="0"  validationpattern="^\d{1,10}$" />
<queryparam paramname="@CustomerLevelID" paramtype="runtime" requestparamname="CustomerLevelID" sqlDataType="int" defvalue="0"  validationpattern="" />
<queryparam paramname="@affiliateID"     paramtype="system"  requestparamname="AffiliateID"     sqlDataType="int" defvalue="0"  validationpattern="" />
</query>

<query name="Features" rowElementName="Feature" runif="showproduct">
<sql>
<![CDATA[ exec dbo.BSI_GetProductCategories @ProductID ]]>
</sql>
<queryparam paramname="@ProductID"       paramtype="request" requestparamname="ProductID"       sqlDataType="int" defvalue="0"  validationpattern="^\d{1,10}$" />
</query>
```

My template calls the "product" data first like so:

```
<xsl:template match="Product">
```

Now, how can I get the data from the 'Feature" call into the Product dataset?  Something like:

```
 <xsl:variable name="feats" select="document(Features)" />
 <xsl:value-of select="$feats/Feature" />
```

Thanks bunches!

Comment: How is the XSLT being launched, and how are you passing it the data from the Products query? Related question: what consumes/executes the above `<query>...` code?

Comment: Thanks for the response, LarsH.  The values are being saved in parameters and accessed like this:  `code`<xsl:param name="pChassisMod" select="aspdnsf:GetMLValue(ChassisModel)"></xsl:param>
I am using aspdotnetstorefront as a backend.  I am not sure what the aspdnsf:GetMLValue() is.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not so much on the xsl side of things, but on how aspdotnetstorefront used the data.  I got around my particular problem by modifying the procedure outlined here: http://forums.aspdotnetstorefront.com/showthread.php?17159-Display-Product-s-Mapped-Categories-on-ShowProduct-aspx-simpleproduct-xml-config

Thanks